# Creating callbacks with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright, so I'm a little confused on how to create callbacks in JavaScript and a mix of jQuery.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
function saveArtDep(vars, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'j_artDepAjax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: vars,
            success: function(data) {
                // callback to fire when success
            }
        });  
}
```

The reason I want to do this is to be able to re-use this function and having a different "loading" message for what I need it for. In other words, the scenario would look like this:

```
$('div#job').html('loading...');

saveArtDep('job_id=3&update_art=true', function(){
             $('div#job').html('success!');
});
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You can pass anything to `callback` and we make sure that it is a function before executing it, in the below seen code.

```
function saveArtDep(vars, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'j_artDepAjax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: vars,
        success: function(data) {
            // callback to fire when success
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        }
    });  
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I knew it was something as simple as that...I don't know why it didn't make sense to me at the time.

Comment: @Dimitri Thats okay :)

Answer (score 2):

In `saveArtDep` the parameter `callback` refers to a function, so you can invoke it using  `callback()`

```
function saveArtDep(vars, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'j_artDepAjax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: vars,
            success: function(data) {
                // callback to fire when success
                callback();
            }
        });  
}
```

Comment: you've got a typo there - callbakc() should be callback()

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function(data) {
  if(typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback(data);
  }
}
```